# a thinner "ring of integers" $\mathcal{O}$

Tags: fonts, math-mode

Throughout [Neukirch's *Algebraic Number Theory*](http://books.google.com/books?id=YUBOcgAACAAJ), he denotes Dedekind domains and their extension respectively with a small and a large version of what I can only describe as a thinner (i.e., less bolded) `$\mathcal{O}$`, which is commonly used symbol to denote the ring of integers of a number field.

[image]

Here is a usage in the book where it is side by side with the standard `$\mathcal{O}$`:

[image]

How can I reproduce these symbols? They don't appear to be in the standard alphabets (like `\mathcal`, `\mathfrak`, etc.).

Comment: On TeX.SE, visualization of TeX is usually done through an image upload, rather than a rendering via MathJax, say. I've removed that from your post since most people know this. See [Why doesn't maths render as maths?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1272/5764)

Comment: For symbol lookup or identification, see [How to look up a symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764) Are you able to find your symbol using any of the methods described in the linked post? Give some feedback.

Comment: @Werner: No, it's not in the "Comprehensive LaTeX symbols" link and  detexify-ing just gave me $\mathcal{O}$.

Comment: @Werner: is there a place where I can see the alphabet rendered into the different math fonts? I'm willing to be that this is symbol is just the letter 'o' in some particular math font.

Comment: See the mathalfa package (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathalfa) for an overview of math alphabets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a resized `\mathcal{O}` to `\scriptsize`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\dedekind}{{$\scriptstyle\mathcal{O}$}}
\begin{document}
\noindent \textbf{(8.1) Proposition.} \slshape Let~\dedekind\ be a Dedekind domain
with field of fractions~$K$, let $L|K$ be a finite extension of~$K$ and~$\mathcal{O}$
the integral closure of~\dedekind\ in~$L$. Then~$\mathcal{O}$ is again a Dedekind
domain.
\end{document}
```

Depending on the usage (commonly standalone or part of math expressions), the following definition might be of benefit:

```
\newcommand{\dedekind}{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle\mathcal{O}}}
```

`\ensuremath` allows you to intermix the usage within math and text mode. A more extensive definition of `\dedekind` would include `\mathchoice` to allow for resizing of `\mathcal{O}` "dynamically" if used in superscript.

Comment: It's also nice to see more examples of where ties are supposed to be used.  I can never figure it out myself.