# How to obtain a lowercase cursive “o”?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

The problem is how to print the following math symbol.  I cannot find it among the Greek symbols.

[image: math symbol]

here is where the "o" i find. I guess it's a special mathfont , and your anwser is very well and i will adopt your solution, but we can go head and find the best solution. thanks again.
[image]

Comment: what is the context here, it is very hard to tell what that symbol is, it looks like an o in a handwriting font, but you hint you are looking for Greek? Where did you find that symbol? If it is in a pdf you can see what character and what font it is.

Comment: To closers as duplicate: I tried Detexify and it gives no real clue. The `mathalfa` package is not mentioned in the Comprehensive List, nor is the Boondox font except for a special letter.

Comment: For an omicron, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233257/omicron-not-working-in-latex

Comment: @egreg thank you, this paper come from Elsevier, I guess the font is the special font from Elsevier.

Comment: @David Carlisle THANK YOU, I thought the character was a Greek alphabet，SORRY.

Comment: No need to apologise:-)

Comment: See also [fonts - a thinner "ring of integers" $\mathcal{O}$ - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61076/a-thinner-ring-of-integers-mathcalo) for a similar symbol.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a lowercase “o” in a script alphabet; the best approximation I can offer is via the `mathalfa` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[scr=boondox]{mathalfa}

\begin{document}

$\mathscr{o}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

@egreg's solution is as close as one is going to get to the symbol you displayed, but here's an alternative.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dutchcal}

\begin{document}

$\mathcal{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$

\end{document}
```